# Allow user interaction during UINavigationController push/pop transition

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-privateapi

Since we do not have control on the animation call when push/pop occur (even by subclassing `UINavigationController`) we can't use the `.allowUserInteraction` option of `UIView.animate` methods.

But after looking at the [private headers](https://github.com/modocache/UIKit-Class-Dump/blob/master/UIKit.framework/iPhoneSimulator.platform/UINavigationController.h), I see that Apple did think of this use case (since at least iOS 8) by providing a private API as well as private flag (`allowUserInteractionDuringTransition`). So there must be a way to allow the navigation controller to allow for user interactions.

How though ??

Comment: I don't need/want to. I want the actual animation to be the default one but I want the user interactions to be working on the  n-1 controller with controller n is popped out.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you want to use a private API for that?

You can implement interactive push and pop transitions via the public `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` API. It's very easy and provides most of the interaction functionality for free, as long as you use `UIView.animate*` methods. `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` abstracts away most of the difficulties and you can even use `UIDynamicAnimator` for cool fluid-like effects.

You could implement the system transitions quite easily this way. You get the pop transition for free with *swipe to go back* anyways - you only need the push.

Here are some examples:

https://theswiftdev.com/2018/04/26/ios-custom-transition-tutorial-in-swift/

https://www.raywenderlich.com/322-custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions-getting-started

https://github.com/marcosgriselli/EasyTransitions

And my personal favorite:

https://github.com/lkzhao/ElasticTransition

If there's something more specific that you would like to achieve that is not covered by the public APIs, perhaps you could provide us with some code?

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure that by using below code, you will be able to achieve whatever you want or not. But, I know how to make call to `private-apis`. Here is a way to make a call to the same.

```
let selector = Selector("allowUserInteractionDuringTransition")
self.navigationController?.perform(selector, with: true);
```

If above not work, then try by changing selector name to `setAllowUserInteractionDuringTransition`.

Hope, this one works for you.

Comment: @apouche I already told you that... i am not sure about will it work or not. but i am 100% sure that private apis are called in this manner.  Probably `allowUserInteractionDuringTransition` this variable is not for what you want.